# Jquery Tag list builder component

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, components

I'm looking for help to find a jquery component that works just like the stackoverflow's tag input... I doesn't need to have a combobox underneath it, just a input that I can add tags freely... Any suggestions?

Comment: I've seen others use this one before https://github.com/max-favilli/tagmanager

Comment: That's more what I'm looking for! Thanks! Can you add an answer so I can set it as right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this jQuery plugin: [github.com/max-favilli/tagmanager](http://github.com/max-favilli/tagmanager)
Good luck :)